# Find idempotent given generator poly and check poynomial by Bezout algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory, euclidean-algorithm, idempotents

I have the cyclic code $C$ of length $8$ and dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and with check polynomial $$g(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^6) = x^4+x^3+x+2$$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_9$ is a primitive 8-th root of unit over $\mathbb{F}_3$

By polynomial division, I find $$h(x) = x^4+2x^3+x^2+x+1$$

---

**Goal: find the generating idempotent $e(x)$**

- I know that it's given by the Bezout identity $1 = a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x)$, so I start dividing $h$ by $g$ (all the division are done in $\mathbb{F}_3$):

$$h =  g + (x^3 + x^2 + 2)$$

- So now I divide $g$ by the term in brackets:

$$g = x(x^3+x^2+2) + (2x+2)$$

- Now I divide $x^3 + x^2 + 2$ by $2x+2$ and I find:

$$x^3 + x^2 + 2 = 2x^2 (2x+2) + 2$$

---

Now I want to obtain the Bezoùt identity, so  I should start from the bottom by writing

$$2 = (x^3 + x^2 + 2) +x^2(2x+2) \quad \star$$

but from the second equation: $2x+2= g +2x(x^3+x^2+2)$

and now I substitute in $\star$:

$$2 = (x^3+x^2+2) + x^2 (g +2x(x^3+x^2+2) )$$

Now, from the first equation: $x^3+x^2+2 = h-g = h+2g$, therefore:

$$2 = h+2g+x^2(g+2x(h+2g))$$

which equals (multiply by 2 both sides):

$$1 = h(2+x^3) + g(1+2x^2+2x^3)$$

---

**Therefore the idempotent $e(x)$** should be: $$e(x) =g(1+2x^2+2x^3)= 2x^7+x^6+2x^5+x^3+x^2+x+2$$ but if I square it I don't $e(x)$ again.

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Assuming $\alpha=1+i$ and $\alpha^2=-i$, $i^2+1=0$ were used, we have $e(1+i)=e(-i)=0$ and $e(x)^2\equiv e(x)\pmod{x^8-1}$. I verified this with Mathematica. Can you tell us why do you think this is not an idempotent?

Comment: You can tell at a glance that $e(x)^3\equiv e(x)$ because the coefficients with exponents within the cyclotomic cosets: $\{0\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,6\}$, $\{4\}$, $\{5,7\}$ all agree. This is not enough for idempotence (it would in the binary case!), but it is suggestive.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Honestly, I manually squared everything and it were not equal to $e(x)$. The mistake was I was thinking mod$x^9-1$, instead of $x^8 -1$. I just realized it by reading your first comment, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idempotent was calculated correctly. There was a mistake in the verification phase in that the wrong quotient ring was accidentally used.